# Is there a haftarah that is never read?

Tags: haftarah

There is supposedly a haftarah that even though printed in chumashim and assigned to a parsha that is actually never read

Comment: Where did you hear such a thing?

Comment: This question was asked by a Bais Yakov teacher.

Comment: @DoubleAA it depends on the minhag. Where I daven, they never read the haftorah for parshas Kedoshim, and instead read the Achrei-Mos haftarah two weeks in a row... But I agree that it's a weird question, as my Chumash contains lots of haftarahs for different communities that other communities would never say

Comment: i'm aware of Haftarot that are listed in the Talmud that we no longer follow. Maybe that's what is going on?

Comment: Is this a riddle question?

Comment: @הנערהזה This is apparently Minhag Yerushalayim (to never read התשפוט, to the extent that where necessary they will read הלא כבני כושיים on two weeks consecutively). See the final section [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%94_%D7%97)

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no Haftara commonly printed (excluding a mistaken edition, or something) that isn't used at least occasionally by some community. Note that some are used [very, very rarely](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3898/759), which perhaps might lead someone to doubt if they are ever used.

Comment: I've definitely heard all the ones listed as "Ashkenazi" read. It's possible I've missed some of the ones printed for other _Eidot_.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, but could you source your statement somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Technically if there was a haftarah different from Shmini Atzeres (in Eretz Yisrael) or Simchas Torah (in the galus) assigned to V'zos Habrachah, then it would never be read. That would be since V'zos Habracha is never read on an individual Shabbas. However, I have never seen a reference to such a haftarah in any seforim or chumashim.

One could also consider what haftarah would have been read when the Torah was read in the tri-ennial cycle. I do not know what the minhag was for that cycle and none of them are printed in the single year cycle chumashim. They would therefore not apply as a possibility.

Note that [What is the rarest Haftarah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/what-is-the-rarest-haftarah/3913#3913) gives the list of rarest haftarah.

Comment: None of those are printed in Chumashim...

Comment: @DoubleAA I said that they would not apply as they are not printed in modern chumashim.

Comment: Here's the triennial list https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85796/759