# Is there a list of the haftorot for the tri-annual torah reading cycle?

Tags: history, torah-reading, haftarah

Based on the assumption that when the [tri-annual cycle for reading the torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triennial_cycle) was prevalent there were accompanying haftorot I would like to know if a list exists of what those haftorot were.

I understand this cycle is currently in use by certain non-orthodox denominations. I do not know if the haftorot those denominations use matches what was used originally.

Comment: "I understand this cycle is currently in use by certain non-orthodox denominations." This is inaccurate. The ancient triennial cycle is not used at all anymore.

Comment: Ah! @DoubleAA mentioned an interesting point. You should edit your question so that it is clear which triennial cycle you mean.

Comment: @DoubleAA, what of Machon Shilo? Do they not use a triennial cycle like that used in E"Y before the Crusades?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Hmm I don't know. I still wouldn't call them a "non-orthodox denomination" as unorthodox as they may be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A full list can be found [here](https://faculty.biu.ac.il/~ofery/papers/haftarot3.pdf) with ongoing updates and sources [here](http://faculty.biu.ac.il/~ofery/papers/Haftarot%203%20years%20_%20Ofer.xls). Many times we only know the opening verse and not the exact end point.

Comment: Of particular note are the Haftarot for sections #27 #31 #46 and #77 which in some traditions have supplanted the original annual-cycle Haftarot for those sections.