# "Riot Act" Haftarah for Kedoshim -- When Will We Read it Again?

Tags: calendar, haftarah, parashas-kedoshim

[As discussed previously](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73031/21), while we avoid it whenever possible, this year (5784 / 2024) most Ashkenazim will read the actual Haftarah for Kedoshim: [Yechezkel Ch. 22](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.22.1-19?lang=bi), "Inform the bloody city of all its abominations!"

The answer there said the last time it was read was 5757 (1997); after this year, what's the next time it will be read? (Better yet, where's a good place to look up stuff like this?)

Comment: The best place to check historical or future year configurations is the table of years in the Tur OC 428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This haftarah is only read in year type [זח"ג](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA_%D7%96%D7%97%D7%92), which next occurs in 5801 (2041).

(The linked Hebrew Wikipedia page is as good a place as any to look this kind of stat up, I guess.)

Comment: Wowww ... thank you. Hebrew Wikipedia is really smart, y'know something?

Comment: This type of year happens 5.8015% of all years.